# PHP routing improvement with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-routing

### Problem

I have a routing set up for php with `.htaccess` where it routes everything to `url/project/`; *[Details about the current `.htaccess` code is given after this section]*

#### How it is currently set up

let's say, I am working in xampp and url is `http://localhost:8000/`, if the project folder name is `php_launcher`, the full url is `http://localhost:8000/php_launcher/`. Any request is redirected to the `index.php` present in the project root folder except for:

1. `/static/*` -> folder that contains static files like images, css, js etc.
2. `/node_modules/*` -> self explanatory.

But what I want it to do:

- when static folders are accessed, it is accessed as `url.../static/file/to/grab.extension`. But what I want instead is `url.../file/to/grab.extension` i.e. to remove the `static/` from url. **This is only for `static` folder and not `node_modules` folder**
- The files are accessed only if it has a extension and not a uri, else it'll redirect to `index.php`. Example: `/css/style.css` will work properly and treated as static files. but `/css/` will be treated as requested uri and the request is sent to `index.php`
- To limit the types of files that can be accessed from static. i.e. The files will be fetched only if the file extentions are allowed like `.png`, `.css` etc.

### What I have

#### Current `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php_launcher/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/node_modules/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) node_modules/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/assets/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/node_modules/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

#### Important file structure

```
- htdocs/
    |- php_launcher/
       |- static/
       |- node_modules/
       |- core/
       |- index.php
       |- .htaccess
```

## Edit

So in the *"what I Want section"*, there is a change:

On point 1, Instead of that it would be:

1. Any URLs requesting for a file (with allowed extensions if possible) will grab the corresponding file from `static/` folder.

### What I tried:

So, to achieve it, I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php_launcher/

# Route requests to assets folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) assets/$1 [L]

# Route requests to node_modules folder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/node_modules/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) node_modules/$1 [L]

# Redirect non-existing files to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]

# Redirect existing files to /static/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ static/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

#### ERROR

But I am getting a Internal server error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.10 Server at localhost Port 8888
```

Comment: You said you wanted to rewrite `static/` URLs, but in your .htacess I don't see any of that? And instead there's `assets`, that gets special treatment, which does not appear to match anything in your folder structure? Please clarify.

Comment: _"The files are accessed only if it has a extension and not a uri"_ - they're _all_ URIs; what you mean here is the difference between a _file_, and a _folder_. Your RewriteConds with `-f` only check if the argument is an existing file; if you want to test for an existing folder as well, you need to add a condition with `-d` (And join both conditions with the `OR` flag.)

Comment: @CBroe I do want that but not yet implemented because I am yet noob at apache and tried various things but did not work. So the code given is the current `.htaccess` without improvement. I believe I explained it in the question with title *How it is currently set up*

Comment: @CBroe I added more info, check it.

Comment: You got a 500 Internal Server Error, so the first thing you should do is go check the error log, and find out the _reason_.